# When is passing a subprogram as a parameter necessary

Tags: language-agnostic, parameter-passing

I've been reading a Concepts of Programming Languages by Robert W. Sebesta and in chapter 9 there is a brief section on passing a `SubProgram` to a function as a `parameter`. The section on this is extremely brief, about 1.5 pages, and the only explanation to its application is:

> When a subprogram must sample some mathematical function. Such as a Subprogram that does numerical integration by estimating the area under a graph of a function by sampling the function at a number of different points. Such a Subprogram should be usable everywhere.

This is completely off from anything I have ever learned. If I were to approach this problem in my own way I would create a `function object` and create a function that accomplishes the above and accepts `function objects`.

**I have no clue why this is a design issue for languages because I have no idea where I would ever use this**. A quick search hasn't made this any clearer for me.

Apparently you can accomplish this in C and C++ by utilizing pointers. Languages that allow nested Subprograms such as JavaScript allow you do do this in 3 separate ways:

```
function sub1() {
    var x;
    function sub2() {
        alert( x ); //Creates a dialog box with the value of x
        };
    function sub3() {
        var x;
        x = 3;
        sub4( sub2 ); //*shallow binding* the environment of the                                 
                      //call statement that enacts the passed 
                      //subprogram
        };
    function sub4( subx ) {
        var x;
        x = 4;
        subx();
        };
    x=1;
    sub3();
    };
```

I'd appreciate any insight offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to pass "methods" is very useful for a variety of reasons.  Among them:

- Code which is performing a complicated operation might wish to provide a means of either notifying a user of its progress or allowing the user to cancel it.  Having the code for the complicated operation has to do those actions itself will both add complexity to it and also cause ugliness if it's invoked from code which uses a different style of progress bar or "Cancel" button.  By contrast, having the caller supply an UpdateStatusAndCheckCancel() method means that the caller can supply a method which will update whatever style of progress bar and cancellation method the caller wants to use.
- Being able to store methods within a table can greatly simplify code that needs to export objects to a file and later import them again.  Rather than needing to have code say

  ```
  if (ObjectType == "Square")
    AddObject(new Square(ObjectParams));
  else if (ObjectType == "Circle")
    AddObject(new Circle(ObjectParams));` 
  etc. for every kind of object
  ```

  code can say something like

  ```
  if (ObjectCreators.TryGetValue(ObjectType, out factory))
    AddObject(factory(ObjectParams));
  ```

  to handle all kinds of object whose creation methods have been added to `ObjectCreators`.
- Sometimes it's desirable to be able to handle events that may occur at some unknown time in the future; the author of code which knows when those events occur might have no clue about what things are supposed to happen then.  Allowing the person who wants the action to happen to give a method to the code which will know when it happens allows for that code to perform the action at the right time without having to know what it should do.

The first situation represents a special case of callback where the function which is given the method is expected to only use it before it returns.  The second situation is an example of what's sometimes referred to as a "factory pattern" or "dependency injection" [though those terms are useful in some broader contexts as well].  The third case is commonly handled using constructs which frameworks refer to as events, or else with an "observer" pattern [the observer asks the observable object to notify it when something happens].

Comment: Your answer was well rounded and easy to understand. I wish I could transport it into my book. Thank you very much.